# (PHP) Are overlapping images possible in PDFs generated by TCPDF or domPDF?

Tags: php, image, tcpdf, overlap, dompdf

We need two images to overlap. The one image is of a plug, and the other is of a cable. Placing them side-by-side isn't good enough because the plug has a curved edge, and so the cable doesn't appear to be connected to the plug due to the white space between the plug's curved edge and the cable's edge.

Now when rendering this effect in HTML on the browser, we use overlapping divs, which are easy to implement using fixed positions / negative margins / etc. Thus in order to make the two images look connected, we've given the plug image a transparent background, and have placed it over the image of the underlying cable.

However we need to achieve the same effect in a PDF report, and we haven't been able to find a way to overlap two images in HTML rendered in PDFs generated by TCPDF. We've also tried domPDF without luck.

Perhaps one of you TCPDF / domPDF gurus out there have a solution? We're also open to out-of-the-box solutions that  achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be achieved with absolute positionning, but will work a lot better with dompdf 0.6 beta 3.

You'll need to wrap the two images positionned absolutely with a container positionned relatively.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Fabien. We didn't try it so I can't confirm whether it works or not, but I have selected your answer as the correct one nonetheless. Please see my other answer below with regards to the solution we ended up going with.

Answer (score 0):

We decided to use the command line tool wkhtmltopdf (with a PHP wrapper) which did the trick.

In fact if you're in the same boat as us where you're wanting to generate PDFs from HTML strings, I highly recommend you check out wkhtmltopdf. It's lightning fast and has far better HTML / CSS support than TCPDF and domPDF.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm a dompdf developer, and our team wants to improve dompdf to be a better product ;) 0.6 has lots of improvements compared to 0.5. Thank you for accepting my answer!